# Why people try to kill or protect the Gods' pawns in Malazan series?

Tags: books, malazan

I have only read Gardens of the Moon series and I am not sure why some people try to kill the tools (pawns) of the Gods where people try to protect them.

For instance Rake doesn't kill Paran when he learns he is not Oponn's tool but his second-in-command Serrat tries to kill the coin bearer. Baruk alto tries to protect the coin bearer at all cost whereas Lorn tries to kill him.

What difference does it make to kill a tool? Is it that easy to kill a tool without the God's help (I mean if there is nobody else to protect the tool)? What are the motives of people who are trying to kill or protect the pawns of the Gods?

PS: Please do not give spoilers if they are related with other books.

Regards

Comment: Everyone in the series has their own motivations; you really just need to keep reading.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield But some people died (i.e. Adjunct). Do I still get to learn her motivations?

Comment: some of them yes you will learn more about what they were trying to accomplish; others, not really, we can only guess.

Comment: yeah answering this question for you would spoil the other 17-20ish books lol

Comment: @Himarm Alright then :) I think most of the questions I am going to ask will require spoilers which will ruin the joy of the books. It is best for me to RAFO I guess. Can this question be closed please?

Comment: @iso_9001_ its actually a decent question, its just that answering it will give spoilers, so i suggest you leave it open, and either answer it yourself when you finish the series, or post a comment in here towards me or mike and we can probably then answer it. or we can answer it now with spoiler tags and you will just wait to look at till you finish the books haha :P

Comment: @Himarm Both of us know for sure that that spoiler tag will NOT stay closed until I finish the books :) Thank you for the suggestions. I will do as you say and answer my own question until I finish the books. Thank you again.

Comment: @iso_9001_ i was constantly skimming the malazan wiki while reading the series, i was all about spoilers with it,